# How do I find a ring with a primary ideal having n elements?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, finite-rings

I would like to know how can I find a ring with (at least) a primary ideal which has n elements (not generators, but elements) for a given n ?

Thank you.

Comment: For instance, for $n=2$, $n=3$ which is the expected answer?

Comment: @dan_fulea I would suppose that the ideal generated by $x$ in $F_2[x]/(x^2)$ and $F_3[x]/(x^2)$ would suffice in both those cases? This can be adapted to work with prime powers, as well. But in general I think the remaining $n$'s are going to be the case to figure out.

Comment: @rschwieb The ring $\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^2)$ has four elements $0, 1, x, 1+x$. Yes, we have the prime = maximal ideal $(x)$...

Comment: I got it now, thank you! :)

Comment: @RuxandraMihaelaIchim If you got an answer, you should write it below. It's OK to self-answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be any ring with $n$ elements and let $S$ be any domain.  Then $R\times 0$ is an ideal in the ring $R\times S$ which has $n$ elements, and it is prime since the quotient $R\times S/R\times 0\cong S$ is a domain.